# VS2019 BC37225 Failure writing debug information: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Ran into the following issue. VS2019 V.16.11.13 VB .Net Solution.
The error appears as soon as you start DEBUG.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a corrupted Solution or Project because it started working OK once I restored them from the source control. Please add anything else you may find that solves this issue as I could not find much regarding it on the web.